# Java - Pass a subclass to a construstor typed to a superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

I am trying to make a manager for a section of classes.

```
public Manager(int amount, Class<SuperObject> c) {
    array = new SuberObject[amount];
    for (SuperObject o : array) {
        try {
            o = c.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Do stuffs
        }
}
```

That works just fine but when I make the call:

```
Manager man = new Manager(5, SubClass);
```

I get a failure to compile because it is not expressly SuperClass.  Any guidance would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Just checking: It looks like you have `SuberObject` with 'b' and `SuperObject` with 'p' ... If it's not a misspelling error, maybe is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class<SuperObject>` expects a `SuperObject` to be given, **and only a `SuperObject`**. Use `Class<? extends SuperObject>` instead.

Comment: The class `Class` was generified in Java SE5.  `Class<SuperObject>` is semantically equivalent to the class literal `SuperObject.class` which is why only SuperObject instances can be accepted by your original code.  In order to allow subclasses of SuperObject, you must use the bounded wildcard type.